# Is there any way to delete yourself in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instance, destroy

I already know that you can delete the obj on which the script is sitting by calling

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

but in my case, I have the same object duplicated many times and deleting it through the script

is deleting other instance of that same obj

Anyway here's my code

```
public void Take_Damage(float amount)
{
    health -= amount;

    if (health <= 0)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }


}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can delete other `Gameobject` or `component` with `Destroy()`.
To delete other Game object from the script you need to get a reference of that GameObject.Then simply use `Destroy(ReferencedGameObject)`

Comment: Yeah but you can also do the same because "gameObject" refers to the obj on which the script is sitting

Comment: yes now let's assume we have 2 cubes that has your script attached and each of their health is 100, now it depends from which object I call `Take_Damege()` if i get reference from cube2 script and call it like following `cube2Script.Take_Damage(100);` then it would only destroy cube 2, cube 1 would not be affected.

Comment: Okay, but the obj which I have to destroy is my enemy so I don't know how many of those I would have that's why I can't use the referencing and then changing way
''

Comment: This might help https://youtu.be/MZOrGXk4XFI?t=524

Comment: Thanks For your help that really helped but I realized that I was subtracting health globally and not of that particular obj thanks